# What are the benefits / advantages of `in` operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

`in` operator seems to be available since forever ago.

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};
if ('foo' in obj) {
   console.log(obj.foo);
}
if (undefined !== obj.foo) {
   console.log(obj.foo);
}
```

The two `if` blocks in the code above do the same thing.  This example itself may be too simple, but by reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), to me, I wouldn't use it.  Besides typing less characters and readability, are there any benefits / advantages that I don't see?  Can you give me a good example of `in` operator usage?

Comment: If you initiate obj with `{foo: undefined};` you get a different result as your seconds example looks at the value of `foo` the `in` operator does not

Comment: They don't do the same. As per the link you posted: `If you set a property to undefined but do not delete it, the in operator returns true for that property.` So in that case the first `if` will log foo while the second will not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example that shows a use case for this:

```
var obj = { foo: undefined }

obj.foo !== undefined; // false
'foo' in obj;          // true
```

When using the `in` operator, you test if the property is specified in the given object and not its value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did read that and it's my bad I didn't mention it. I prefer `obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')` for that case.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> If you set a property to undefined but do not delete it, the `in` operator returns true for that property.

So, the `in` operator can be used to find if a property exists in an object, even if it is `undefined`. The second way you show, `undefined !== obj.foo`, will return false if the property doesn't exist, OR is undefined.

Example:

```
var obj = { myProp: undefined };

'myProp' in obj; // = true
obj.myProp !== undefined; // false
```

I can see this being useful if you want to confirm that a property exists on an object before assigning a value to it, since the assignment will work even if the property didn't previously exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did read that and it's my bad I didn't mention it. I prefer `obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')` for that case.

Answer (score -1):

Using the in operator in javascript we not also can check for a particular property but can iterate over the list.

The ES 5 specification details two distinct syntaxes for the for-in statement:

1.**for (var variable in objectExpression) {statement}**

2.**for (LeftHandSideExpression in objectExpression) {statement}**


For Ex.

If i have an Array object like

```
var objarray=new Array('rakesh','naresh','dinesh','nilesh');
```

then i can directly loop over the Array Object.

```
for(var a in objarray)
{
console.log(objarray[a])
};
```

The output we get is:

```
rakesh
naresh
dinesh
nilesh
```

So the 'in' operator has other benefits other than only checking value.